# How to select children of a div with a known ID when they have indeterminate IDs?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

As part of a Google Chrome extension that I'm building, I need to inject some code into a webpage that will add some elements to its DOM.

One problem I've encountered is how to select particular child elements when the webpage creates different, indeterminate, IDs for them on each load. I've provided an example below.

Assuming that outerDiv1 and outerDiv2 have stable IDs and I want to select the child of outerDiv2 with the "inner" class, what is the best way of doing this?

```
<div id = "outerDiv1">
   <div class = "random"></div>
   <div id = [INDETERMINATE] class = "inner"></div>
</div>
<div id = "outerDiv2">
   <div id = [INDETERMINATE] class = "inner"></div>
   <div class = "random"></div>
</div>
```

One solution is to create a function like this:

```
function findChildWithInnerClass(divID) {
   var children = divID.childNodes;

   for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      if (children[i].className === "inner") {
         return children[i];
      }
   }
}
```

And then call it with the live element of outerDiv2.

However, this seems a bit long-winded. Is there a faster way of doing this with selectors that I can apply using document.querySelector()?

I'm only interested in pure JavaScript answers, by the way, no jQuery please.

Comment: If you are just interested in childDivs containing .inner you can use document.querySelectorAll('#outerDiv1 .inner');

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? From the sound of it you want to pick up a click event of a specific dom element in children and handle it? (bubble up) but you are coding it from a top down fashion (propagation). Top down coding for user interactions is always going to be hard if you can't uniquely identify user interaction points further down the dom tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector("#outerDiv1 .inner")`.

You can use any CSS selector.

It will return one node or `null` if it doesn't find anything.

If you wish to select all nodes corresponding to your selector, you can use `document.querySelectorAll("#outerDiv1 .inner")`, which will return a `NodeList` object, like `document.getElementsByTagName`.

This is supported on IE8+, Chrome 4+, Firefox 3.5+, Safari 3.2+, Opera 10+.

Comment: "*You can use document.querySelector("#outerDiv1 .inner")...It will return a NodeList object*" - No, it won't; `document.querySelector()` will return either a DOM node - the first node found in the document that matches the supplied selector - or `null`; you're probably thinking of `document.querySelectorAll()`.